# SQL Work out the average time difference between total rows

Tags: mysql, sql, time, average

I've searched around SO and can't seem to find a question with an answer that works fine for me. I have a table with almost 2 million rows in, and each row has a MySQL Date formatted field.

I'd like to work out (in seconds) how often a row was inserted, so work out the average difference between the dates of all the rows with a SQL query.

Any ideas?

-- EDIT --

Here's what my table looks like

```
id, name, date (datetime), age, gender
```

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding the question... a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-window.html) like `select date - lag(date) over (order by date) ...`?

Comment: I think you could use `(max(date)-min(date))/(count(*)-1)`. No need for calculating the diff between each row.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to know how often (on average) a row was inserted, I don't think you need to calculate all the differences. You only need to sum up the differences between adjacent rows (adjacent based on the timestamp) and divide the result by the number of the summands.

The formula

```
((T1-T0) + (T2-T1) + … + (TN-TN-1)) / N
```

can obviously be simplified to merely

```
(TN-T0) / N
```

So, the query would be something like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(date), MAX(date)) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
FROM atable
```

Make sure the number of rows is more than 1, or you'll get the Division By Zero error. Still, if you like, you can prevent the error with a simple trick:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(date), MAX(date)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0)
FROM atable
```

Now you can safely run the query against a table with a single row.

Comment: This will skew the result in cases where the first or last dates are outliers, e.g., where the first date is 10 years ago and all other dates are in the last year. By averaging the differences instead, you will get a more accurate picture.

Comment: @RedFilter: Sorry, I don't follow you. You mean, it would be better to calculate the average by actually following the `((T1 - T0) + (T2 - T1) + ... (Tn - Tn-1)) / N` formula?

Comment: @RedFilter: My solution implements the reduced (or 'simplified', I'm not sure what's the correct English for the term) version of that formula, i.e. `(TN - T0) / N)`.

Comment: +1 This must be selected answer. This is the simplest way and its give a fast calculation of avg time.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot:

```
select AVG(theDelay) from (

    select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,a.date, b.date) as theDelay
    from myTable a
    join myTable b on b.date = (select MIN(x.date) 
                                from myTable x 
                                where x.date > a.date)

) p
```

The inner query joins each row with the next row (by date) and returns the number of seconds between them.  That query is then encapsulated and is queried for the average number of seconds.

EDIT:  If your ID column is auto-incrementing and they are in date order, you can speed it up a bit by joining to the next ID row rather than the MIN next date.

```
select AVG(theDelay) from (

    select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,a.date, b.date) as theDelay
    from myTable a
    join myTable b on b.date = (select MIN(x.id) 
                                from myTable x 
                                where x.id > a.id)

) p
```

EDIT2: As brilliantly commented by Mikael Eriksson, you may be able to just do:

```
select (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,(MAX(date),MIN(date)) / COUNT(*)) from myTable
```

There's a lot you can do with this to eliminate off-peak hours or big spans without a new record, using the join syntax in my first example.

Comment: I cancelled the query after it was still going for 7 minutes... I get the impression it might be in some kind of infinite loop

Comment: @tamfeld You did say there are ~2 million records... Give it time, it is not in an infinite loop.  It has to join ~2 million records against ~2 million records, calculate the seconds between ~2 million dates, and then average ~2 million integers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select avg(diff) as AverageSecondsBetweenDates
from (
    select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.MyDate, min(t2.MyDate)) as diff
    from MyTable t1
    inner join MyTable t2 on t2.MyDate > t1.MyDate
    group by t1.MyDate
) a
```