# Get average time between record creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I have data like this:

```
UserID  CreateDate
1       10/20/2013 4:05
1       10/20/2013 4:10
1       10/21/2013 5:10
2       10/20/2012 4:03
```

I need to group by each user get the average time between CreateDates. My desired results would be like this:

```
UserID  AvgTime(minutes)
1       753.5
2       0
```

How can I find the difference between CreateDates for all records returned for a User grouping?

EDIT:

Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `(5+1500)/2 = 752,5`?

Comment: @Lamak you are correct; I was thinking I used 4:10 not 5:10, thanks. But its still (5+1500)/3 but that user has three results getting returned for an average of 501.67 minutes over the three.

Comment: @Tonnie - no, it should be `753.5` - there are three _records_ but only two _differences_.

Comment: @Tonnie It should be divided by 2, since there are 2 time lapses between your rows for `UserID=1`

Comment: you guys are correct!

Comment: Similar (same actually, just for a different product): [SQL Work out the average time difference between total rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191310/sql-work-out-the-average-time-difference-between-total-rows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  A.UserID,
        AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.CreateDate,A.CreateDate) AS FLOAT)) AvgTime
FROM #YourTable A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM #YourTable
             WHERE UserID = A.UserID
             AND CreateDate < A.CreateDate
             ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) B
GROUP BY A.UserID
```

Comment: This gives `NULL` for user 2. That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: This works, thanks! I can just wrap the AVG statement in an ISNULL to turn the NULLs into 0s

Comment: Let's hope that it's impossible to create two records with the same date and userid

Answer (score 2):

This approach should aslo work.

**[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84ba5/10)**:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    Select userId, createDate, 
           row_number() over (partition by userid order by createdate) rn
    from Table1
)
select t1.userid, 
       isnull(avg(datediff(second, t1.createdate, t2.createdate)*1.0/60),0) AvgTime
from CTE t1 left join CTE t2 on t1.UserID = t2.UserID and t1.rn +1 = t2.rn
group by t1.UserID;
```

**Updated:** Thanks to @Lemark for pointing out `number of diff = recordCount - 1`

Comment: You are using a value of `0` for the first value of `UserID = 1`. This shouldn't be taken into account on the average

Comment: @Lamak; [check this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84ba5/4), second one is your query and it isn't giving those values either. Bit confusing with the values.

Comment: Because op was wrong on his calculation and mine was correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501789/get-average-time-between-record-creation?noredirect=1#comment28928501_19501789

Comment: @Lamak, updated and giving the same results as yours. Redirecting to comment is a nice one.

Comment: yup. Tried to add a comment saying that you didn't need to delete your answer, just to stop using `ISNULL`

Answer (score 2):

since you're using 2012 you can use lead() to do this

```
with cte as
(select

         userid,
       (datediff(second, createdate, 
                    lead(CreateDate) over (Partition by userid order by createdate)
                   )/60) datdiff


From table1
)
select 
  userid,
  avg(datdiff) 
from  cte
group by userid
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/758a8/9)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY CreateDate) RN,
      UserID,
      CreateDate
   FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
  T1.UserID,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, ISNULL(T2.CreateDate, T1.CreateDate), T1.CreateDate)) AvgTime
FROM CTE T1
  LEFT JOIN CTE T2
    ON T1.UserID = T2.UserID
      AND T1.RN = T2.RN - 1
GROUP BY T1.UserID
```

Comment: [Why `mi`? Why not spell out `MINUTE`?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Where is difference?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think you must edit your blog's post mentioned above depending on [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Aaron's post is talking about good practices, it never says that it doesn't work, just that people can confuse the abbreviations and use the wrong ones. Why use a shortcut when you can explicitely write `MINUTE`?

Comment: @Hamlet I don't know what you mean. Try `SELECT DATEPART(Y, GETDATE());` to understand why shorthand is bad and spelling out what you mean is good.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In your blog you have the matching chart of the short and long forms. There is a mistake in it.

Comment: @Hamlet what mistake? That I didn't list all of them? That was intentional and wasn't the point of the exercise. Maybe read the whole post or tell me a little more explicitly what mistake you think exists, because I don't follow what you're saying is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL 2012 you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function and self-join to find the "previous" row in each group:

```
WITH Base AS
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY CreateDate) RowNum,
    UserId, 
    CreateDate
FROM Users
)
SELECT 
    B1.UserID, 
    ISNULL(
       AVG(
           DATEDIFF(mi,B2.CreateDate,B1.CreateDate) * 1.0
       )
    ,0) [Average]
FROM Base B1
LEFT JOIN Base B2
    ON B1.UserID = B2.UserID
    AND B1.RowNum = B2.RowNum + 1
GROUP BY B1.UserId
```

Although I get a different answer for UserID 1 - I get an average of (5 + 1500) / 2 = 752.

Comment: [Why `mi`? Why not spell out `MINUTE`?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This only works in 2012. You can use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
  id integer,
  created datetime not null
);

INSERT INTO dates (id, created)
SELECT 1 AS id, '10/20/2013 4:05' AS created
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '10/20/2013 4:10'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '10/21/2013 5:10'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '10/20/2012 4:03';

SELECT id, isnull(avg(diff), 0)
FROM (
  SELECT id,
    datediff(MINUTE,
             created,
             LEAD(created, 1, NULL) OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY created)
             ) AS diff
  FROM dates
) as diffs
GROUP BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ce89/22